# Why does Haskell have isIEEE if it always evaluates to True?

Tags: haskell

The Haskell `RealFloat` typeclass has a function called `isIEEE` which, according to the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:isIEEE), gives 'True if the argument is an IEEE floating point number' (and, one would imagine, False otherwise).

But here's the implementation of `isIEEE` for `Float`:

```
instance RealFloat Float where
  ...
  isIEEE _ = True
```

And here's the implementation for `Double`:

```
instance RealFloat Double where
  ...
  isIEEE _ = True
```

If `isIEEE` is always unconditionally `True`, why use it? Why have it in the Prelude at all?

Comment: Just because the only `RealFloat` instances that come with GHC obey IEEE754, it doesn't mean you can't define your own instances which don't.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Wait, you can actually define your own floating point type?

Comment: @WanderNauta That's the point of typeclasses, as long as you can provide the functions you can have your type as an instance of it.

Comment: @Koterpillar Neat! That actually makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Additionally, you could theoretically be running Haskell on some bizarre platform that doesn't have IEEE754-compliant floating point hardware. (Although I think this is pretty unlikely...)

Comment: BTW, this method uses the ancient habit of passing an argument that is purely by convention never looked at, just to dispatch on its type. These days it is considered cleaner practice to use `Proxy`, which ensures the actual value of a type *cannot* matter (because none is passed).

Comment: Once upon a time IEEE-754 non-compliance was a real possibility. So it made sense to have this flag. These days of course its largely (entirely?) redundant, as I doubt you could buy non-compliant hardware if you tried. But there may be software out there that won't compile without it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [leftaroundabout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745903/leftaroundabout) and [Koterpillar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288201/koterpillar) mentioned in the comments, it is possible to define your own instances of RealFloat. These custom-made float types do not necessarily have to follow the IEEE standards.

```
instance RealFloat MyFloat where
  isIEEE _ = False
  ...
```

Additionally, if your floating-point type isn't IEEE, you are allowed to have all RealFloat predicates return False:

> (...) The functions isNaN, isInfinite, isDenormalized, isNegativeZero, and
>   isIEEE all support numbers represented using the IEEE standard. For
>   non-IEEE floating point numbers, these may all return false.
>
> [Haskell 98 Report, 6.4.6](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/basic.html)